# Redirecting after Python Cloud Function

Tags: python, python-3.x, forms, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

My HTML form has

```
action="https://us-central1-PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/FUNCTION_ID"
```

with

```
method="post" target="_blank"
```

The link sends an email address string to a Google Cloud Function in the Python 3.7 Beta Runtime.

The function performs correctly and interacts with a third party API.

After the function runs it loads a blank page with

```
OK
```

as the only content. From here I'd like to redirect back to my website but I can't quit figure out how to do this.
Ive tried

- Placing a urllib.request at the end of my Python function
- Performing an XMLHttpRequest
- Changing

  ```
  target="_blank"
  ```

  to

  ```
  target="_self"
  ```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: What is "your website"? It sounds like you should probably be making the call to the function from your backend, not directly from the browser.

Comment: Change the form to a button, the on click, issue the post request to the cloud function url. On success do a window.location = “yourpage”

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm using Firebase hosting in this instance so I don't believe I really have a backend? I'm using Cloud Functions because I wanted to attempt a full server-less implementation for this project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google Cloud Functions uses [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) under the hood to serve your endpoint, so you can just return a [`redirect`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.redirect) at the end:

```
from flask import redirect

def test(request):
    return redirect('https://google.com')
```